# Symfony2 - cannot submit other forms on pages with login form

Tags: forms, symfony, authentication, form-submit, firewall

When I create firewall area for login form I suddenly cannot submit other forms on that page.

In my case, in contacts page I have contact us form and it is working just fine, but when I add this to security.yml:

```
firewalls:
    contacts:
        pattern:    ^/contacts
        anonymous:  ~
        provider:   main
        context:    primary_auth
        form_login:
            login_path:             /contacts
            check_path:             /contacts
            default_target_path:    /authorization
        remember_me:
            secret: '%secret%'
            lifetime: 31536000
```

My contact form just stops working (cannot submit). When I press submit button `$contactForm->isSubmitted()` and `$contactForm->isValid()` both are returning `false`.

The same problem appears in homepage. My sign up forms stops working if I add login form configurations in firewall for homepage.

Maybe anyone had same problem and know the solution?

Comment: Did you create a named form via the `form.factory` service? How are both forms created? My guess would be that they both have the same name because you create them via the controller `->createFormBuilder` method which gives both forms the same name.

Comment: @Rvanlaak, my login form is created in the view using simple <form> tag like documentation shows:
http://symfony.com/doc/current/security/form_login_setup.html

Comment: @Rvanlaak, I deleted login form but I still not able to submit contact form untill I delete firewall. I am not sure it is forms fault.

Comment: I think you'll need to change the `login_path` and `check_path`, they are already behind the firewall so in order to do the authorization check you actually have to be authorized. That way the firewall will not process the form.

Comment: @Rvanlaak it seems that check_path was the problem, I changed it from `/contacts` to `/contacts/login_check` and now it works :) could you post it as answer so I could accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your configuration puts `check_path` behind the firewall already, so in order to perform the login check users already have to be logged in.

Change your configuration to a path like `/login-check` that isn't included in `pattern`:

```
firewalls:
    contacts:
        pattern:    ^/contacts
        # ..
        form_login:
            login_path:             /login
            check_path:             /login-check
            # ..
```